# Why doesn't $(functionName()) work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code works as expected:

```
$(function() { 
    $("tr:odd").css("background-color","#dddddd");
})
```

And this doesn't:

```
function temp() {
    $("tr:odd").css("background-color","#dddddd");
}

$(temp());
```

Why?

Comment: I am sure both work as expected, it just depends on what you expect.  Please clarify your expectations.

Comment: temp is the function, temp() is the result of executing the function. $(temp()) results in temp being immediately executed instead of having it executed when the DOM becomes ready, which is what you wanted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

because you should write

```
$(temp)
```

since temp is a callback

what you are doing in the second snippet is

```
$(temp()) // => $(undefined) since temp doesnt return anything
```

Comment: It should be 'undefined' not 'null' in the comment

Comment: @mihai It actully should be null because, if you look through the jQuery code it returns null not undefined

Comment: right , should return undefined ( the function temp ) ,but $() actually returns null i think.

Answer (score 2):

In your second example you are passing the result of the `temp` function. You need to pass it's body. So, use this:

```
$(temp);
```

instead of

```
$(temp());
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery expects a callback. Try:

```
$(temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(function()` is a shortcut to `$(document).ready`, which basically runs on page load.
Therefor, in your top solution, you were adding the function when loading and not doing so in the bottom one.

Try this:

```
function temp() {
    $("tr:odd").css("background-color","#dddddd");
};

$(function() {
    temp();
});
```